# get difference between 2 dates in milliseconds

Tags: date, datetime

Hello all my question is that i have two dates Like $date1 = 2021-05-04 15:52:32 and $date2 = 2021-05-05 15:52:32 how to calculate difference in milliseconds between this dates in php please help.

Comment: Use `strtotime()` to covert the date string to milliseconds

Comment: ok i am converting both dates into strtotime and minus date1 from second is it true or not

Comment: Its true. It should work

Comment: then how to check the difference time is correct or not??

Comment: By giving calculated date time